# Can I extract a VBA module from an Access Database?

Tags: apache-poi, ole, text-extraction, jackcess

I have a database (.mdb) with mostly tables/queries and an VBA module with some functions that are used in queries. I try to make a full textual extract of the database as a "diffable" text file that I can version-control.

I tried but could not get at the VBA code with Jackcess, is this possible?

Or can the OLE-support in Apache POI be used for this?

Comment: Good question!  Once a year when I do maintenance on a legacy Access app at work I wish I could do this for the VBA code.  I've been getting by with zip files and readme.txt file to explain the changes.